# How to change two buttons' colors in a stackpanel

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two buttons in a stackpanel and I want to change one's background and other's foreground to the same color.

I tried this in xaml.

```
<StackPanel 
    Style="{DynamicResource LeftStackPanel}" 
    MouseEnter="StackPanel_MouseEnter"
    MouseLeave="StackPanel_MouseLeave"
    >
    <Button 
        x:Name="profile_rct" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
        Height="70"  
        VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        Width="7"
        Background="{Binding
                     Path=BackgroundBtn, 
                     Mode=OneWay}" 
        BorderThickness="1,1,1,1"
        BorderBrush="DimGray" />

    <Button 
        x:Name="profile_txt" 
        Content="Profil Bilgisi"
        Style="{DynamicResource LeftButton}"
        Foreground="{Binding
                     Path=BackgroundBtn, 
                     Mode=OneWay}">
        <Button.LayoutTransform>
            <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
        </Button.LayoutTransform>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

In `LeftStackPanel` it only has positional arguments, so I don't think it is important. In `profile_rct` I bind background to `BackgroundBtn` and in `profile_txt` I bind the same variable to foreground this time. In `LeftButton` style there is no value for foreground.

In code here is `StackPanel_MouseEnter` and `BackgroundBtn` codes.

```
 #region ViewModelProperty
    private Brush backgroundbtn;
    public Brush Backgroundbtn
    {
        get
        {
            return backgroundbtn;
        }

        set
        {
            backgroundbtn = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Backgroundbtn");
        }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string v)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion
```

---

```
private void StackPanel_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Backgroundbtn = Brushes.CadetBlue;
    }
```

There are two problems here, even though I write the event on stackpanel, color of items only changes when I point them and only the color of pointed item is changing. I want to change colors of both items.

Second is it doesn't change foreground of profile_txt but background. I didn't understand that.

Answer (score 0):

Learn binding in WPF: http://www.cheat-sheets.org/saved-copy/WpfBinding.pdf
In your case:

```
Background="{Binding ElementName=BackgroundBtn, Path=Background, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that stands out is a difference in case: `BackgroundBtn` is not a property on your ViewModel, but `Backgroundbtn` is.

Is that the issue?